# How to insert a number if character is upper?

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
def func(s):
    dict = {
          'a': 1,
          'b': 2,
          'c': 3 }

    #Split input into list
    split = list(s)

    #gather output list
    output = []

    for x in split:
        output.append(dict.get(x))
    print(output)

func("abc")
```

the output is:

1, 2, 3

**Goal:**

if the input contains a capital letter, how can i place value '00' before the capital letter?

for example if the input is 'Abc' the output will be '00, 1, 2, 3'

**One method:**

One of the solutions I know is simply place the capital letters into the dictionary and have a value of '00'. But does anyone know a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Well, `if isupper(my_string)...` springs to mind. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an `if` to check if a given strings `isupper`:

```
def func(s):
    d = {
          'a': 1,
          'b': 2,
          'c': 3 }

    #Split input into list
    split = list(s)

    #gather output list
    output = []

    for x in split:
        if x.isupper():
            output.append('00')
            output.append(str(d.get(x.lower())))
        elif x in d:
            output.append(str(d.get(x)))

    return ', '.join(output)
```

---

```
func("abc")
# '1, 2, 3'


func("Abc")
#' 00, 1, 2, 3'
```